# Is there a way to deploy different portion of the same codebase to differente prod environments?

Tags: php, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, web-deployment

I have a codebase that needs to be deployed to a production environment, so far all good.
The same codebase, need to be deployed to a different production environment, but not all of it, just some parts.
Is there a a way to automate this process?

I'll ad an example hoping to make this more clear:

Let's say i have 3 php pages (A, B, C) in my dev environment and I want to deploy all 3 (A, B, C) of them on one web server and just 2 (A, B) of them to another one.

And when i update one of the pages it should be deployed only to the proper environment, meaning that if i update page A or B the update should be deployed to both prod environment, and if I update page C this should just be pulled by one.

Comment: Is it problematic if all pages are available on both servers? What happens if page C is available on the second server?

Comment: If I was using rsync, I might have something like an excludes file, you could have different ones for different environments, but this feels somewhat messy and you'd have to be careful and methodical (and document it).

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes, one of the environment is an intranet, and all the funcionalities should be available to users. The other one is the extranet, and not everthing should be exposed to the outside world. We currently have about 10% of the codebase on the extranet, but we maintain it manually. I'd like to setup something more straightforword, it would be great to have annotations or something like that to handle this automatically

Comment: There are many automated configuration and deployment platforms out there, depending on your budget and your taste for getting your hands into the details (Jenkins, for example, or Capistrano, or Ansible, or Puppet, or literally dozens of others). If your case is fairly simple, can't you just script deployment yourself?